# Run a Query Before Activating OnClick Function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an onclick function. According to the item that user selects, it opens up a dialog which display `Document Type`, and `File Names` (downloadable files in .pdf format) which are available to download under this item.

The `ItemNo` has to match the`Document Type` it belongs to, otherwise the dialog opened will not display any information.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="ItemNo" HeaderText="Item No" SortExpression="ItemNo"
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="#" onclick="openDialog('/SitePages/FileDownload.aspx?DocType=<%= docType %>&ItemNo=<%#Eval("ItemNo")%>&CustomerID=<%#Eval("CustomerID")%>')">
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Right now, my `DocType` is hard coded in the code behind.

Is there a way to use Javascript, or backend code to check for the `DocType` of `THCItemNo` first, before moving on the onclick event when the user clicks on an item?

---

Backend:

```
    protected int docType=60;

    protected int DocType
    {
        get
        {
            return docType;
        }
    }
```

Let me know if other code is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion: you verify your `DocType` by a request ajax to the server. If ok, you can `openDialog`, if not, you show nothing

For exemple,

```
<a href="#" onclick="checkAndOpenDialog(<%= docType %>, otherParams)"></a>

function checkAndOpenDialog(string docType, otherParams)
{
    $.get( "url", docType, function(data) {
        openDialog('/SitePages/FileDownload.aspx?params;
});}
```